# Azure Pack Websites Default Website

Tags: azure

Does anybody know if it is possible to configure a default URL associated with the Front End of an Azure Pack Web Sites cloud?

So rather than getting the ugly 404 Not Found IIS page, a redirect to some other page is returned?

Even better, I want to attach the original request uri as a query string to the redirected web page.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can configure your front end servers to have custom error pages. Here are the locations where they are:

[image: Azure Pack Websites custom error pages locations]

You can setup you own ASPX pages or what not instead, and use

```
redirectMode="ResponseRewrite"
```

In the web.config. Then you can use aspxerrorpath to recover the original url, see [this post for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070695/accessing-original-url-in-iis7-404-redirect-page).